# Maui SearchBar and Popup

Tags: popup, searchbar, maui-community-toolkit

I have spent two days but at the end I've understand the problem of my app but I'm not sure if I have made a mistake or what...

I have this XAML file, a simple searchbar and a button that execute the same command:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout>
  <SearchBar SearchCommand ="{Binding RicercaAnagraficaCommand}">
  </SearchBar>
  <Button Command="{Binding RicercaAnagraficaCommand}"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

And the Command in the viewmodel il this:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async void RicercaAnagrafica ()
{
   await App.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(new AnagraficaPopUp());
}
```

When I hit button on the app it open the PopUp normaly. When I hit the enter key on the SearchBar the app open two PopUp (one over the other).

Have I made some mistake or what?

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML, add the SearchButtonPressed event to the SearchBar:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <SearchBar SearchCommand="{Binding RicercaAnagraficaCommand}" 
               SearchButtonPressed="OnSearchButtonPressed">
    </SearchBar>
    <Button Command="{Binding RicercaAnagraficaCommand}"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

In the ViewModel, handle the SearchButtonPressed event and prevent the default behavior:

```
private async void OnSearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Prevent the default behavior of the SearchBar
    ((SearchBar)sender).IsEnabled = false;
    ((SearchBar)sender).IsEnabled = true;

    // Execute your command here
    await RicercaAnagrafica();
}
```

Comment: I don't underrstand (I'm newbie). You write to handle in the Viewmodel the event of the SearchButtonPressed. I'ts not handled in the code behind that event? If I must use it in the viewmodel, how can I link them between the XAML and the viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when you trigger this event with a void, and not a task, you get two event. So try using Task

```cs
[RelayCommand]
async Task RicercaAnagrafica()
{
    await App.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(new AnagraficaPopUp());
}
```